# Debugging ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Tags: pandas, dataframe, series

I am trying to resolve a value error comparing identically-labeled Series objects.

I have looked at previous stackoverflow examples as well as other online sources but they have not been helpful. I am trying to select rows with the same randomTime from a dataframe patientFrame, and appending it to a new dataFrame newFrame.

```py
newFrame = pd.DataFrame()

for identity in patientList:
    patient = int(identity)
    patientFrame = data.loc[data['person_id'] == identity]

    randomselect = patientFrame.sample(n=1) 
    randomTime = randomselect['symptom_start_date']

    timeExtract = patientFrame.loc[patientFrame['symptom_start_date'] == randomTime] #This is where the error occurs

    newFrame.append(timeExtract)
```

The error occurs above as noted. Is part of the issue that comparing the series objects within the dataframe, and that I should instead try converting them all to strings? I did try this approach but was not successful initially.

Comment: `randomTime` is a Series, you can see this if you add a `print(type(randomTime))` just after that. Thus when the comparison happens things aren't aligned. Do `randomselect['symptom_start_date'].item()` when you define it since you always sample with `n=1`

Comment: So I made the changes you recommended, and right now I have this: `timeExtract = patientFrame.loc[patientFrame['condition_start_date'] == randomTime]
    print(timeExtract)`. The problem is that when I run it, the output says "Empty DataFrame". I know this cannot be true, so what do you think the error is? Is it an error in the comparison?

Comment: It may be easier to think about creating randomTime with the following syntax `randomTime = patientFrame.sample(n=1).loc[:,'symptom_start_date'].iloc[0]` which should yield a value only.

Comment: Without a [mcve] it's very difficult to know exactly what is going wrong. I suggest you add in a ton of `print()` statements after each and every line to ensure everything is happening as you think. For instance, check what `patient` is, then check that `patientFrame` isn't empty after you mask it.

Comment: @CJR's recommendation resolved the issue. Thank you very much!